# Como usar o Recycleview no fragmento ?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Não sei se formulei a pergunta corretamente, mas vamos lá quem poder me ajudar agradeço :)

essa é minha segunda MainActivity, estou fazendo uma aplicação com navigation drawer e nela pra fazer as outras telas do menu estou usando os fragmentos, porém eu quero fazer uma lista em cada menu, mas não sei como fazer isso dentro de uma classe que extende fragment...

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recyvlerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));

}
```

}

Aqui é o adapter:

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
Context context;
// array para receber as imagens
ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();




public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    // imagens
    images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.tn_gpx15));
    images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.tn_gpx19));
    images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.tn_tb));
    images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.tn_gpx15));
    images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.tn_gpx19));
    images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.tn_tb));


}

public MyAdapter(Fragment_main fragment_main) {

}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // setando imagens, posições.
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return images.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_imagesview);


    }
}
```

até aqui tudo bem, funciona tudo certo e me retorna a lista de imagem, [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mais eu queria fazer o mesmo no fragmento, lá eu tentei fazer a mesma coisa,

public class Fragment_main extends Fragment {

```
RecyclerView recyclerView2;

public Fragment_main() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View Acess = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) Acess.findViewById(R.id.my_recyvlerview2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));

    return Acess;
}
```

}

porém no trecho LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false); fica acusando que não é compatível, na parte do context.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

queria saber como resolver isso e exibir essa lista no layout do fragmento...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você está trabalhando em Fragment, vc deve usar `getActivity();` no lugar do `this`

exemplo:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = 
    new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
```

Comment: valeu funcionou antes eu cheguei a colocar getcontext kkk, muito obrigado leonardo dias, me ajudou muito, lembrando que pra quem ta vendo essa postagem e está com mesmo problema, tem que substituir os dois this por getActivity()...